# Serializable dictionary, how to set key name?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Question: I use a serializable dictionary class, found at 
http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx
, to serialize a dictionary.
Which works fine, but I run into an annoying problem.

```
      <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("DataBase")> _
    Public Class cDataBase
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlNamespaceDeclarations()> _
        Public ns As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces()


        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Tables")> _
        Public Tables1 As New SerializableDictionary(Of String, cTable)


    End Class ' cDataBase
```

When I serialize instances of the above class, as this, 
the created xml looks like this:

```
<Tables>
<item>
  <key>
    <string>MyTable</string>
  </key>
  <value>
    <Table CreationDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00" LastModified="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
      <Columns>
        <Column Name="PrimaryKeyName">
          <DataType>Uniqueidentifier</DataType>
          <Length>36</Length>
        </Column>
      </Columns>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Item>Reihe1</Item>
          <Item>Reihe2</Item>
          <Item>Reihe3</Item>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Item>Reihe1</Item>
          <Item>Reihe2</Item>
          <Item>Reihe3</Item>
        </Row>
```

Which would be good if only I could figure out how to rename the key from
<string> to something defined in an attribute

```
  <key>
    <string>MyTable</string>
  </key>
```

Basically something like the XmlArrayItem attribute, such as below, if (only) the dictionary were an array...

```
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("Tables")> _
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("Table")> _
        Public Tables As New List(Of cTable)
```

I wanted to try to change Of String to a custom class inherited from string, which I could equip with a name, but the problem is, one cannot inherit from string...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to change your serialized output from this:

```
<Tables>
  <item>
    <key>
      <string>MyTable</string>
    </key>
    <value>
      <!-- snip -->
    </value>
  </item>
</Tables>
```

To something like this:

```
<Tables>
  <item>
    <key>
      <TableId>MyTable</TableId>
    </key>
    <value>
      <!-- snip -->
    </value>
  </item>
</Tables>
```

You also mention that one way you could achieve this would be to create your own type which inherited from `System.String`, which - as you also mention - obviously isn't possible because it's `sealed`.

You *can* however achieve the same result by encapsulating the key value in your own type, and then controlling the `XmlSerializer` output using an `XmlTextAttribute` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx)):

> By default, the XmlSerializer
>   serializes a class member as an XML
>   element. However, if you apply the
>   XmlTextAttribute to a member, the
>   XmlSerializer translates its value
>   into XML text. This means that the
>   value is encoded into the content of
>   an XML element.

In your case you'd use the attribute as follows:

```
public class TableId
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And then use this type as the key(s) to your `Dictionary`.  Which should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could specialize the Dictionary template or derive from a specialization to serialize as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's probably somewhat off topic, I need to ask why use XML to serialize it? If you just want to save the object state for the future I would suggest JSON instead of XML.

One large benefit is you can easily save a normal Dictionary class without having to write any special code. The payload is also much smaller as JSON so it's a great format to send across the wire if needed.

Scott Gu has a bit of info about using the JavascriptSerializer [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx). I would suggest making it an extension method on object. Then you can do this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
myDict.Add(10,"something");
string jsonData = myDict.ToJSON();
```

If this is something your interested in let me know and I can post the code for the extension methods I use. (sry not at work and I don't have them with me here.)

Comment: First, I'm limited to .NET 2.0, and second, the main problem is that dictionary is a generic type and NOT SERIALIZABLE (not in JSON either). I'm serializing to XML because XML is broader used, and better to read, if serialized from .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the source you can modify it so that it looks up XML attributes if they are present. There's nothign sacral about XML attribure family - the are just like any other attrib that can be looked up via reflection. Once yo u have that you can put new names into the code where in creater and/or reads XML tags. You can also just add 2 params to override tag names explicitly, like ReadXml(myReader, "Tables", "Table") and change the code to follow these names instead of defaults. Got to switch to C# though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing Dictionary with KeyedCollection. It is serialized as a list, as a result it is smaller and XML node names are names of cTable properties/fields.

```
[Serializable]
[CollectionDataContract]
public class TablesCollection : KeyedCollection<string, cTable>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(cTable item)
    {
        return item == null ? String.Empty : item.TableName;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can't say that i've used that implementation of serializeable dictionary, but in case you're willing to try new things, there is a little known abstract class called KeyedCollection which is fully serializeable, supports key based access, and can be easily implemented as dictionary.

[.Net 2.0 Keyed Collection](http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2007/09/27/The-NET-20-KeyedCollection-maybe-your-most-valuable!.aspx)